# Difference between DTLS-SRTP and SRTP packets send over DTLS connections

Tags: webrtc, sip, rtp, dtls

I have two SIP endpoint and wanted to send the media over DTLS-SRTP. I am little bit confuse in below points

1. Is DTLS-SRTP and SRTP packets send over DTLS connections are same or different ?
2. If different, Could you please explain me how are they different ?

Comment: There is no difference. DTLS-SRTP means SRTP packets sending over DTLS connection.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

DTLS is utilized to establish the keys that are then used for securing the RTP stream. Once the keys are established, they are used to encrypt the RTP stream to make it SRTP(nothing special about the encryption, [standard SRTP rfc3711](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3711)) and then sent over that DTLS channel. If you read [rfc5764](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5764), you can get more specifics about what a DTLS channel is and demultiplexing the packets, etc.

So, DTLS is key MANAGEMENT for the SRTP exchange. See [rfc5764 section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5764#section-4.1) for a little example.

In summary: if by SRTP over a DTLS connection you mean once keys have been exchanged and encrypting the media with those keys, there is not much difference. The main difference is that with DTLS-SRTP, the DTLS negotiation occurs on the same ports as the media itself and thus packet demultiplexing must be taken into account over those ports.

Comment: So SRTP data is transmitted via DTLS, and not plain UDP, correct?

Comment: @Rubycon see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48946111/1818849

Comment: Got it, so it's SRTP over plain UDP

Answer (score 16):

The above answer is *almost* correct. In DTLS-SRTP, a DTLS handshake is indeed used to derive the SRTP master key.

However, once the master key is obtained, DTLS is not used to transmit RTP : RTP packets are encrypted using SRTP and sent directly over the underlying transport (UDP).

Comment: Found your answer easier to understand. Respect.

Comment: Is it really uses plain UDP under the hood to transfer SRTP data OR it uses DTLS?

Comment: DTLS is purely used for key derivation during the handshake. The actual media is encrypted using SRTP, which is directly on top of UDP, no DTLS involved.